# In-app rating system using google play game services, possible?

Tags: android, google-play-games

Is it possible to implement rating system for in-game objects (just like app rating in google play store) using Google Play Game Services API?

I never used it before and didn't find suitable chapter, but may be it has low level API for such things.
Or may be Leaderboard API can be used somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [RatingBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html). It is not part of the Google Play Games Services API, but it will allow you to implement a star rating system.

Comment: RatingBar is just a widget, it is not a problem. I need complex solution with server side. And free if possible.

Comment: @ucdevs If that's the case, you'll probably need to implement it yourself, with your own server. There is no Google product that I know of that provides this service.